# Looking for a simple web interface with subversion support and ticket /issue tracker

Tags: web, interface

I am working on a small project and we have a few programmers on the job. We are using subversion to commit updates and keep all developers up to date on their workstations.

However, we have yet to find a suitable web interface to use for it. I have tried redmine, but that installation progress was extremely bothersome and advanced. Once I got it to work I found out that it was slow and did not meet my expectations. As well as it seems a bit complex for our needs.

I would prefer to find a solution that supports lighttpd web server, however that seem to be very hard to come by, those I have found seem to only have apache support.

Functionality i wish for the website:
- login to an svn account
- view svn logs
- view & create issues, todo list etc
- view svn difference

Do you have any open source recommendations that I can try out? I will appreciate any kind of reply. :)

Edit: I wish to host the website on our own servers.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on StackOverflow, or better yet, a forum since there are several options available.

Comment: Also, svn sucks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)

Comment: Trac also has plugins for other SCMs like Mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I dumbed this down for a hobby team game project and stuck with plain Subversion and Trello for basic issue and feature tracking. It works well, though won't scale much. To access Subversion without a client, WebSVN is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

[Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) is what I've used for this before. Worked like a charm and is completely free.

Comment: Remember to provide links for stuff like this, you'll get more upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

I use https://bitbucket.org/ but it’s for git or mercurial.